# PHP File Upload - Can't Upload / Debug

Tags: php, windows, file-upload, iis-express

I'm trying to upload a file but i doesnt work:

Usefull Info: Running IIS Express (with PHP 5.3) - Windows 7 Professional 32 Bits

Code:

> move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagem"]["name"], "/images/" . $_FILES["imagem"]["name"]) or die ("Error:".print_r($_FILES));

**It Prints:** Array ( [imagem] => Array ( [name] => Chrysanthemum.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\php3D85.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 879394 ) )

I'm sure the path is correct and i also did chmod() to set permissions but still, doesn't upload.
Any sugestions?

Comment: the first parameter should be `$_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name']` and try using `./images/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your destination path should start with a proper path to the images directory (`dirname(__FILE__)` can help). As it stands, `"/images/" . $_FILES["imagem"]["name"]` means it'll try to write to `C:/images/` (assuming the script is in the `C:` drive) which probably doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Since its is inside of an array you need to execute the move uploaded file function inside of foreach loop.

```
foreach($_FILES['imagem'] as $f){
move_uploaded_file($f['tmp_name'], "/images/" . $f["name"]);
}
```

You might wanna try using my class:
http://code.google.com/p/daves-upload-class/source/browse/upload_class.php